# Why does release block do not free the resource?

Tags: anylogic

Hi i have a source linked with a seize block,which contains 3 resources (see image)
[image: image1]

I want  the resource "motrice" be the first to be released, so i used two release blocks. (see image)
[image: image2]

the problem is that the release1 block does not free the resource and i do not know why.
As you can see from the last two images, after the agent go trough the release1 block, the resource "motrice" is still linked to the agent.What is the error?Thanks

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

Comment: you should try to reproduce your model in a smaller version... if you are not able to, then you are hiding important information that will help you solve... i couldn't reproduce this problem myself

Comment: the resource motrice is only in this seize. Between the start and the  wait, there are only pickup and dropoff. In the smaller version the release work.

Answer (score 0):

I created similar model with two options:

- one with pickup before seizing the resources;
- one with pickup after seizing the resources.

As you can see from the below screenshots, it does release "motrice" in both cases. It might be due to the pickup/dropoff or the resource is seized somewhere else, not related to these blocks that you have mentioned.

[image]

Comment: the resource is seized only in these block (i checked ). But i noticed that if i choose in the release1 block "All seized from resources from given pool (s) " (always selecting "motrice"),the problem is resolved, but i still want to know the reason of the first error.

Comment: I tried "All seized from resources from given pool (s)" and "Specified quantity of resources". In both cases, "motrice" is released.